# Angular - Display Item by Category

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic4

I would like to display the books under its category but as LoadBooksByCat(catId) is called for each category Id, it will updates all the previous books that was displayed to the new list

```
categories: Observable<any[]>;
 myBooks: Observable<any[]>;
 
 this.db.GetDatabaseState().subscribe(rdy => {
  if (rdy) {
    this.categories = this.db.getCategories();
    }
}

LoadMyBooksByCat(catId){
    this.myBooks = this.db.LoadBooksByCat(catId);
  }



  
  <div *ngFor="let cat of categories | async">
          <ion-label>
            {{ cat.CategoryName }}
          </ion-label>
          
        {{LoadMyBooksByCat(cat.id)}}

        <ion-row>
        <ion-col *ngFor="let books of myBooks | async">
          <ion-item>
              <ion-label>{{books.bookName}}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
       </ion-row>

</div>
```

this is getCategories and LoadBooksByCat method which I called from the service

```
getCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
  return this.categories.asObservable();
}

LoadBooksByCat(catId:number){
  let mybooks: mybooks[] = [];
   this.database.executeSql('SELECT mybooks.bookName, mybooks.id, mybooks.catId, Category.CategoryName AS mybooks FROM Books JOIN Category ON Category.id = mybooks.catId WHERE mybooks.catId=' + catId, []).then(data => {
    
    if (data.rows.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {   
        mybooks.push({ 
          id: data.rows.item(i).id,
          catId: data.rows.item(i).catId,
          bookName: data.rows.item(i).bookName
         });
      }
    }
    this.mybooks.next(mybooks);
  });
  return this.mybooks.asObservable();
}
```

Here is what Categories and Books db looks like

Categories

id  CategoryName

1, 'Finance'

2, 'Communication'

Books

id  catId   bookName

1,  1,      'Finance 101'

2,  1,      'Basic Economy'

3,  2,      'Crucial Conversation'

4,  2,      'Influence'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but that service call where it seems you are passing raw SQL from the client is a bad idea if thats what its actually doing... `this.database.executeSql()`

Comment: why do it it with interpolation? do this code in ts, so your calls will be synchronous and can be handled easily to render on html

Comment: @NiangMoore call your category in subscribe of it call grtbooks.. create a map and once all done.. then use that map in html...  .in ur current code there is lot of async code..make it sequential..

Comment: @minigeek thanks your suggestion worked!

Comment: @NiangMoore I added it as answer. pl consider accepting if it helped .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is lot of asynchronous operations happening in your code. Make it sequential.
Instead of using string interpolation, make changes in .ts file

Call getbookbycat inside subscribe of getCategory so it will more synchronous and create a map to render on HTML. This will print your key value pair of each category and its book.